# Qual é a origem da palavra “cágado”?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia

Estava lendo uma imagem de humor de quanto o cágado, este tipo de tartaruga de água doce, sofre por conta do acento.

Fiz uma pesquisa sobre a origem da palavra, mas não encontrei nada relevante.

O que encontrei é exatamente como está em uma das respostas, que a origem é desconhecida ou é um tipo de brasileirismo, este via Google ("cágado significado").

Refiz a busca e descobri que [cágado em galego](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1gado) é girino. A cabeça desse tipo de tartaruga lembra um pouco um girino, muito pescoçudo. Não sei se tem alguma relação.

Talvez de alguma forma *Chelidae*, o nome científico, tenha se transformado em “cágado”, mas não achei nada que pudesse comprovar isso e nem o processo.

Qual é a etimologia dessa palavra?

Comment: O "cágado" é um dos motivos pelos quais as palavras proparoxítonas devem levar um acento.

Comment: Do latim científico não pode ser. A palavra *cágado* está atestada já no século XIV (Houaiss).

Comment: O nome científico vem de alguma derivação do radical "χέλυς" (tartaruga), do Grego antigo (como aponta o "CH" com som de "K", usual em palavras gregas latinizadas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A palavra **cágado** é, segundo o [Diccionário Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico](https://archive.org/details/diccionario-critico-etimologico-castellano-g-ma-corominas-joan-pdf/page/n12/mode/1up), cognato da palavra Espanhola **galápago**, que significa um tipo de tartaruga (o tipo de tartaruga que significa varia com a região, aqui na América do Sul, “Galápago” significa, nos países hispânicos daqui, os grandes jabutis das ilhas Galápagos).

Segundo o dicionário etimológico, *galápago* vem de uma língua ibérica pré-romana (isto é, uma língua falada na península ibérica antes da conquista romana), e foi latinizada (isto é, adquirida pelos romanos) como *“*calap(p)acu”*.

Segundo o dicionário, esta palavra pode ser relacionada com, as também de origem ibérica pré-romana, *“*calapaccea”* (*“calabaza”* em Espanhol, *“cabaça”* em Português) e *“*carappaceu”* (*“carapacho”* em Espanhol, *“carapaça”* em Português).

O dicionário ainda aprofunda-se na etimologia ao descrever as primeiras ocorrências escritas, em Latim e Espanhol, da palavra; além de descrever os cognatos e a evolução da palavra e de seus sentidos nas demais línguas latinas da península ibérica (como, por exemplo, no catalão *calàpet/galàpet* que, diferente das demais línguas, significa “sapo” e não “tartaruga”; e em Galego, que significa “girino”).

Aqui no Brasil, chamamos tartarugas não-aquáticas de terra-firme de “Jabutis” (empréstimo da língua Tupi), as tartarugas de água doce de “Cágados”, e as tartarugas marinhas simplesmente de “tartarugas”. Não posso lhe dizer se esta mesma configuração semântica ocorre em Portugal (até porque imagino que tartarugas de terra firme não existam no velho continente).

Comment: *Cágado* em Portugal deve ser mais ou menos isso também. O Domingos Vieira (1873) diz que se deitam aos tanques e poços para lhes limpar o lodo!

Comment: Bem, a favor dessa hipótese está a forma *caagado*, atestada no sXV (Houaiss); a vogal dupla resulta normalmente da supressão duma consoante (*calavaria* > *caaveira* > *caveira*; *Talavares* > *Taavares* > *Tavares*).

Comment: +1 E não é que, um ano depois, acharam as fontes melhores por que eu ansiava? :)

Comment: @Jacinto e quanto às tartarugas de terra firme? Como são chamadas em Portugal? Há um nome para elas? Teria o nosso “jabuti” tupi cruzado o Atlântico?

Comment: São tartarugas, por exemplo, as dos Galápagos. Jabuti, eu nem sabia o que era.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que alguém encontre fontes melhores, mas, até lá, vale registrar que, de acordo com o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/c%C3%A1gado) e o [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/c%C3%A1gado), a palavra 'cágado' tem:

> origem controversa

enquanto o [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/c%C3%A1gado/) o descreve como tendo etimologia

> desconhecida

e a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/c%C3%A1gado) como sendo

> De origem obscura

Então, a menos que esses dicionários se enganem, não sabemos qual é a etimologia dessa palavra.

Answer (score -2):

A origem da palavra Cágado é um nome genérico que designa as tartarugas de água doce, com patas dotadas de membranas interdigitais e unhas.